# Getting the values from jagged array

Tags: c#, .net, jagged-arrays

i want to create a program to take the students name and their marks in 2 subjects, and display them in tabular format, i am using jagged array, if i display just marks it works fabulous, but i also want to include the students name in the displayed info, below is my code.

```
public void GetSquareArray()
        {
            const int STUDENTS = 1;
            const int MARKS = 2;
            string[] numbers = { "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth" };
            string[][] company_details = new string[STUDENTS][];
            for (int i = 0; i < STUDENTS; i++)
            {
                company_details[i] = new string[MARKS];
                /*Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} Student Name", numbers[i]);
                company_details[i][0] = Console.ReadLine();*/ commenting this works fine
                for (int j = 0; j < MARKS; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Marks {0}:", j + 1);
                    company_details[i][j] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < STUDENTS; x++)
            {
                /*Console.Write("STUDENTS {0}: ", company_details[x]);*/ commenting this works fine.
                for (int y = 0; y < MARKS; y++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}\t", company_details[x][y]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
```

can anyone tell me how could i include the students info(name) in the displayed info like it should be displayed like

```
Abbas: 12   12
```

Comment: Well, how is the Student associated with a row? That is, given a particular `x`, how can the student name be determined?

Comment: i guess with the way of row numbers, like for first row, it should display the name of the first student, and so on

Comment: There are *no* student name list in the posted code, but if there was such a list, then `var studentName = studentNames[x];`. In any case, I would recommend using [new] types as I find the names can be used to organize my thoughts and code; say, `class Student { string Name; IList<int> Scores; }; IList<Student> students = ..`

Comment: concerning the 1st _commenting this works fine_ - I can't believe that. It should give you a null-ref exception.

Comment: oh i am sorry, the line "company_details[i] = new string[MARKS];" got commented in SO while adding question, bymistakely, it has not been commented in code

Comment: hi @pst can you please help me with the code to add the students name in the displayed info

Comment: @Abbas Well, since the jagged array is of strings, just uncomment the bit that "reads the user names" and make the marks stored from `1..n+1` (not `0..n`), where `n` is `MARKS`. Make sure to also create `new string[MARKS+1]`, but it's ugly .. again, I'd recommend using new types to help with organization (and Lists to avoid having to know about the size ahead of time).

Comment: but @pst i guess that would just take and display marks.. i want students name too

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} Student Name", numbers[i]);` so just store the username as the "first mark" (or index 0). As I've said twice now, that is fairly hackish.

Comment: i got you, you are fab, thanks a lot dude

Comment: it works fine for the first student name, as while reading i am assigning to company_details[i][0], but that would give index out of bound error, for more students.. how can i handle that, because in the main for loop, i just have the value of i, what i shall assign to 2 dimension